# Is it possible to make outbound call from sip trunk using api?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

We use the following api to make an outbound call. Can we use a sip address in the From parameter to use SIP trunk.

```
    $call = $client->calls->create(
    "+1XXXXXXXXXX", "+1XXXXXXXXXX",
    array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot provide a SIP address as a From parameter when making calls. [The documentation describes the required parameters for a call as](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#required-parameters):

```
Parameter   Description

From        The phone number or client identifier to use as the caller id.
            If using a phone number, it must be a Twilio number or a Verified
            outgoing caller id for your account.

To          The phone number, SIP address or client identifier to call.
```

So, you can only use a phone number or a client identifier. The `To` parameter can be a SIP address, so you can make calls from the API to a SIP address, just not from one.

If you are using SIP trunking you need to initiate calls via SIP.

Comment: Basically I want to use SIP trunking to initiate calls. Can you share the right documentation for this.

Comment: Check out the docs on [getting started with SIP Trunking](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/getting-started) and then [how to configure it with your PBX or SBC](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/sample-configuration).